# a4j:ajax not working with h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We are migrating from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2 and use following components.

Apache myFaces 2.2.12 
Rich Faces 4.3.4

I am facing an issue while replacing `<a4j:support> with <a4j:ajax> for <h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`
Following is the xhtml code.

```
 <h:panelGrid id="info" columns="2">

                <c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="provider">


                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="#{provider.name}" value="#{provider.select}" 
            disabled="false">
                            <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.processProvider}" execute="@this" render="info">
                                    <f:param name="name" value="#{provider.name}"/>
                                </a4j:ajax>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputText  value="prod1"/>

        </c:forEach>

 <h:panelGrid>
```

On checking the selectBooleanCheckbox , listener is not getting called. I have tried following things :

1)Change listener method argument from ActionEvent to AjaxBehaviorEvent.
 2)Change listener method to accept no argument. 
 3)a4j:ajax events tried - change,click,valueChange

Following is the method signature for listener method.

```
public void processProvider(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){

}
```

Nothing seems to be working . 
 Can anyone pleas help ?

Comment: Have you replaced head and body to h:head and h:body? Do you see the request in firebug/dev tools? Do you see any javascript errors in browser console (again, firebug or dev tools can help with that)?

Comment: @andrey:thanks for reply.I am getting the error in console as "ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined" when the check box is clicked. I have confirmed that <h:head> and <h:body> do exist in my facelet page.It is also giving "syntax error" for jsf.js.faces.

Comment: Probably due to that preceding "syntax error" js error, RichFaces javascripts do not have a chance to initialize. Continue checking in firebug (I guess there is a bit more info than "syntax error" text). Try more simple page (e.g. just a single button inside a form), try if f:ajax works.

Comment: @andrey:The syntax error is observed only when rich faces is referenced in xhtml code.If plain JSF 2 tags are used , no error is observed.